# How to display tree results count by each month?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to count achieve 3 results in one query:

1. Count all results where ‘app_creationdate’ = ('month') from current row
2. Count all results where ‘app_start’ = ('month') from current row
3. Count all results where ‘app_creationsdate’ < ‘app_start’ and ‘app_start’ = ('month') from current row

My Table:

app_id | app_creationdate(timestamp) | app_start(datetime) 
00001  | 2014-11-17 19:39:04         | 2014-11-18 09:30:00

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT( app_creationsdate, '%m' ) AS 'month', 
    COUNT( app_id ) AS 'new',
    (SELECT COUNT( app_id ) 
     FROM appointments WHERE MONTH(app_start) = MONTH(NOW())) AS 'act',
    (SELECT COUNT( app_id ) 
     FROM appointments WHERE MONTH(app_creationsdate) < MONTH(app_start)) AS 'prev' 

FROM appointments
WHERE app_owner = 2 AND app_creationsdate > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH)
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT( app_creationsdate, '%Y%m' )
```

Comment: Don't use `DATE_FORMAT` for comparison. MySQL has a bunch of functions that extract parts of dates as numbers.

Comment: What other Solution do you suggest?

Comment: Read the magical MySQL documentation and find out.

Comment: I changed it up i think the Problem ist that instead of getting to Month related to the current row from 'month' i get the actual date instrad!

Comment: Please update your question instead of dumping code in the comments. Nobody is going to read it that way.

Comment: just did that... meybe your going to read it now and help me out? ;-)

Comment: Which column is not giving you the right answer?

Comment: 'act' and 'prev' (Both subquery's) both show the same result on every line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be closer to what you want. I'm still a bit confused about the `prev` scenario, so I did my best. I use `EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM ...)` to get the year and month, without the day, of each date so that we can do monthly comparisons. That's probably what you were trying to do with the `DATE_FORMAT` business.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( app_creationsdate, '%m' ) AS 'month', 
   COUNT( app_id ) AS 'new',
   -- get all other appointments that start in this month
   (SELECT COUNT( act.app_id ) 
      FROM appointments AS act 
     WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM act.app_start) = EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM appointments.app_creationsdate)) AS 'act',
   -- get all appointments that were created before they started (???) and that started before this month

   (SELECT COUNT( prev.app_id ) 
      FROM appointments AS prev
     WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM prev.app_creationsdate) < EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM appointments.app_creationsdate)
       AND EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM prev.app_start) = EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM appointments.app_creationsdate)) AS 'prev' 
  FROM appointments
 WHERE app_owner = 2
   AND app_creationsdate > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH)
 GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM app_creationsdate)
```

Comment: Well at the Moment on running my query i get the Following result: |app_creationdate = (all Months with result) |new  = all rows where app_creationsdate matches month from 'month'|  act = all results from curent month where app_start matches current month | prev = all results from previous months where app_start matches previous months

Comment: @jhondano: first, you are just describing what you expect, not what's actually happening. Second, your description of prev does not match what the SQL does. I'm not sure which one is what you intend.

Comment: just updated question again... i hope now its clear what am trying to achieve?

Comment: @jhondano: not entirely. What does "('month')" mean? Current month (as in, on the day you run the query), or the month of the row produced by the grouping?

Comment: the month of the row produced by the grouping would be correct!

Comment: The third statement should be: get all appointments app_creationsdate < than ‘month’ and ‘app_start’ = ‘month’

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish but I do notice one thing:

DATE_FORMAT(a2.app_start, '%m' ) = DATE_FORMAT('month', '%m' )

This: DATE_FORMAT('month', '%m' )...evaluates to NULL so equating that with anything is never going to work (I don't think anyway, but I'm new to MySQL... :) ).